# Use regex as replacement in regex function?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I'm trying to use a regex function to achieve the following My input looks like this:

```
A:L1, A:K2, A:E3, A:A4, A:E5, A:H7,
,EHKKDH,6,LKEAELH,7
```

I would like to write a regex function that will separate

```
,EHKKDH,6,LKEAELH,7
to:
,EHKKDH,6,
 (blankline)
 LKEAELH,7
```

The function I have for finding what I want to separate is:

```
import re
with open ('masterfile.txt', 'r' ) as f:
content = f.read()
y=str(content)
badpattern= re.compile(r'\d,\w')
goodpattern=re.compile(r'\d,\n\w')
x = re.sub(badpattern,goodpattern,y)
print(x)
```

I get the following error when I use goodpattern in the replacement spot.

```
 File "myprogram.py", line 55, in <module>
x = re.sub(badpattern,goodpattern,y)
File "/Users/Jay/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/re.py", line 192, in sub
return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
File "/Users/Jay/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/re.py", line 309, in _subx
template = _compile_repl(template, pattern)
File "/Users/Jay/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/re.py", line 300, in 
_compile_repl
return sre_parse.parse_template(repl, pattern)
File "/Users/Jay/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/sre_parse.py", line 954, in parse_template
s = Tokenizer(source)
File "/Users/Jay/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/sre_parse.py", line 228, in __init__
string = str(string, 'latin1')
TypeError: decoding to str: need a bytes-like object, re.Pattern found
```

My code works otherwise, if I put a string, 'works', where goodpattern is I get the following output:

```
,EHKKDH,worksKEAELH,7
```

I need to be able to use a regex to do these replacements. the pattern will always be number,letter

Also how would I append these changes to replace the matches in the original file? I understand the replace method. However, I am having a terrible time using re.sub even after consulting the manual. I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

I usually use the site [regexr.com](https://regexr.com/) to construct these kind of regexes.

Anyways, as you said, the pattern is `word` `,` `number` `,`.

Changing this to regex:

`word` -> `\w+` or `[a-zA-Z]+` (`\w` will include numbers aswell, `[a-zA-Z]` will only match chars `A` to `Z` and `a` to `z`. You add the + to match **at least** one character.)

`,` -> `,`

`number` -> `\d+`

Then the final regex will be `[a-zA-Z]+,\d+,`.

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter for `re.sub`, the replacement string, has to be a string, rather than another regex. In your case, you should use capture groups before and after where you want to insert a newline character (or two, if you want a blank line), so that you can use backreferences to refer to them in the replacement string:

```
x = re.sub(r'(\d,)(\w)', r'\1\n\2', y)
```

Comment: Thank you for the regex expression. I greatly appreciate it. I'm a bit confused on what exactly capture groups are. if I include a line that says print(x) after the regex the output I want appears in the terminal window. How do I get this to append to the outfile? I tried f.write() and got io.UnsupportedOperation: not writable

Comment: Glad to be of help. Your outfile needs to be opened in a writable mode. For example, `outfile = open('output.txt', 'w')`.